# angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular.js and my first try was really bad.
I got an error and i tried to debug it, but now i'm a bit frustrated .
Error is

```
angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%3A%2…oogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4630q @ angular.js:322g @ angular.js:4591db @ angular.js:4513c @ angular.js:1777Ac @ angular.js:1798fe @ angular.js:1683(anonymous function) @ angular.js:31018b @ angular.js:3197Rf @ angular.js:3487d @ angular.js:3475
```

This is my code for :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>User Story</title>
</head>

<script src="../app.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Baby Users</h1>
  {{2+2}}
</body>
</html>
```

and for:
app.js

```
angular.module('myapp',[]);
```

Comment: put your script app.js below angular-route.min.js , hope it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script `app.js` should load after `angularjs` reference

**[DEMO APP](https://plnkr.co/edit/p9j5FdlxKi6BZDURN0qC?p=preview)**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>     
<script src="../app.js"></script>
```

Comment: @RishabhAnand check the demo app

Comment: sir, still not working!
Is there a problem with the source of the angular.js file?

Comment: @RishabhAnand whats the error? no my demo app also works with the same version file https://plnkr.co/edit/p9j5FdlxKi6BZDURN0qC?p=preview

Comment: this is the error:

angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%3A%2…oogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4630q @ angular.js:322g @ angular.js:4591db @ angular.js:4513c @ angular.js:1777Ac @ angular.js:1798fe @ angular.js:1683(anonymous function) @ angular.js:31018b @ angular.js:3197Rf @ angular.js:3487d @ angular.js:3475

Comment: @RishabhAnand can you give me team viewer?

Comment: i didnot get it...team viewer?

Comment: https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/current-version/ to check your code

Comment: give me access to check

Comment: how to add you?

Comment: open it , it will display a client id and password, give me that

Comment: 253 128 623 :id
3p5jg  :pw

Comment: @RishabhAnand did you sort it out?

Comment: today it happened again